# matplotlib legend bars and texts are not aligned

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, legend

I use `matplotlib` in `python2.7` to get a figure with multiple trajectories. I am getting this figure as the output of my code:
[image]
However, as you see the title of each trajectory is not aligned with the corresponding color line. I played with the options of `legend`, but did not figure out the solution.

Do you have any idea?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

liste = range(1,13)
labels = ['3-3','3-4','3-5','3-6','4-3','4-4',
          '4-5','4-6','5-3','5-4','5-5','5-6',
          '6-3','6-4','6-5','6-6']

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)

for cnt, j in enumerate(labels):    
    a1 = range(100) # iter
    a2 = np.random.randint(10,size=[100]) # dnn
    a3 = np.ones((100)) # optimal

    if cnt == 0:
        plt.plot(a1,a3,label='BS', color='blue')
        plt.plot(a1, np.divide(a3,a3), color='blue')

    title_font = {'size':'11', 'color':'black', 'weight':'normal',
               'verticalalignment':'bottom'}

    plt.plot(a1,a2,label=j, color='red')


plt.xlabel('episode')
plt.ylabel('cost')
plt.grid(True)

lgd=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.0, 1.0, 0.102), 
                loc=3, ncol=len(liste), mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of the issue, i.e. a code that can be copied and run to produce the same undesired behaviour. Get rid of everything that is not needed here, like the actual data, several `if` clauses etc.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the code as you asked.

Comment: Not really. I edited your code to be useful. You may adapt the image using this code if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend handles and labels do not fit into the legend box. You may see that when removing the `mode="expand"` label.

To get the legend entries take less space, use the `handlelength`, `handletextpad` and the `columnspacing` and play with the parameters until they fit. If that would still not be the case, using less columns is necessary. Set the `ncols` to a lower number.
E.g. with the following

```
lgd=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.02, 1.0, 0.102),
               handlelength=0.9, handletextpad=0.3,columnspacing=0.7,
               loc=3, ncol=9, mode="expand", borderaxespad=0.)
```

one would get an image with all legend entries fitting

[image]